# Is there a way to change the stylings of mat-checkbox on hover?

Tags: css, checkbox, angular-material

I want to change the border-color of mat-checkbox on hover .

Below code is not working

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox:hover .mat-checkbox-frame:hover {
          border-color: red !important;
}
```

My [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyfg2z) . Please help me out .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set(When you style globally like in `style.scss`)

```
.mat-checkbox:hover {
  .mat-checkbox-frame {
    border-color: #ff2222 !important;//what ever color you want
  }
}
```

If in component-style.scss(like header component, footer etc) then use `/deep/` like

```
 /deep/ .mat-checkbox:hover {
   /deep/ .mat-checkbox-frame {
     border-color: #ff2222 !important;//what ever color you want
   }
 }
```